# Dictionary sorted in reverse alphabetical order and max score printed

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a problem with Python dictionary to sort the names in reverse alphabetical order and get max score from scores and print them together. This is the example:

```
 marks = {  "Zane": [25, 58, 66, 42],
            "Kate": [34, 42, 86] }
```

This is what it is supposed to look like: `Kate’s best mark is 86`.

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; please take the [tour] and read [ask], then [edit] to show a [mre] of a specific problem with your attempt to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing keys in reverse order is not really possible in Python3.6+, as all dicts are sorted by key value. However you can do this:

```py
for name, marks_arr in sorted(marks.items(), reverse=True):
    print(f"{name}'s best mark was {max(marks_arr)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your dictionary using the sorted function this way

```
for name in reversed(sorted(marks.keys())):
  print(f"{name}'s best mark was {max(marks[name])}")
```

Note that we iterate through the keys of your dictionary